# Xcode: Provisioning Profile Expired message on archiving, but all Profiles are up to date

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I have just made some updates to my app and have gone archive it in preparation for uploading to the store.

However, I get the error `Provisioning Profile has Expired`.

I logged in to my developer account and activated the inactive profiles. I then cleaned the build and tried again but still get the same error.

Would anyone know whats going on and how to fix this?

Comment: Download newly activated profile & drop into Xcode then build & check....

Comment: @Vishal do I just drop it onto the xcode icon in the dock? That doesnt seem to change anything

Comment: Yes drop in Xcode & then check in organizer that your profile is valid or not....

Comment: @Vishal ah yep it says it is valid in the Organizer but I still get the error

Comment: Reset your organizer & then check....Means refresh...

Answer (score 0):

download the newly created provision double click it. This will add the provision and you can see from the organizer which will open as a action of the double click. Now clean your project. select the new provision from build Settings to make the build. This will solve your problem.